# ARKIT stereo - move objects

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I have two ARSCNView sessions side by side for stereo view. I am trying to create a box in stereo view and then make it spin.

All works fine until I move the parentNode using self.parentNode.runAction

The movement only occurs in the right side view (SceneView2). No movement occurs in the left side view. Views are also offset. I need the movement to be synchronized in both the left and the right views.
Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import SceneKit
import CoreLocation
import GLKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
@IBOutlet weak var SceneView2: ARSCNView!
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

var parentNode: SCNNode!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addBox()
    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.worldAlignment = .gravityAndHeading
    configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    movebox()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    sceneView.session.pause()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    // Present an error message to the user
}

func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
    // Inform the user that the session has been interrupted, for example, by presenting an overlay
}

func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
    // Reset tracking and/or remove existing anchors if consistent tracking is required
}


// UPDATE EVERY FRAME:
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.updateFrame()
        //self.movebox()
    }
}

func updateFrame() {
    // Clone pointOfView for Second View
    let pointOfView : SCNNode = (sceneView.pointOfView?.clone())!
    // Determine Adjusted Position for Right Eye
    let orientation : SCNQuaternion = pointOfView.orientation
    let orientationQuaternion : GLKQuaternion = GLKQuaternionMake(orientation.x, orientation.y, orientation.z, orientation.w)
    let eyePos : GLKVector3 = GLKVector3Make(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    let rotatedEyePos : GLKVector3 = GLKQuaternionRotateVector3(orientationQuaternion, eyePos)
    let rotatedEyePosSCNV : SCNVector3 = SCNVector3Make(rotatedEyePos.x, rotatedEyePos.y, rotatedEyePos.z)
    let mag : Float = 0.066 // This is the value for the distance between two pupils (in metres). The Interpupilary Distance (IPD).
    pointOfView.position.x += rotatedEyePosSCNV.x * mag
    pointOfView.position.y += rotatedEyePosSCNV.y * mag
    pointOfView.position.z += rotatedEyePosSCNV.z * mag
    // Set PointOfView for SecondView
    SceneView2.pointOfView = pointOfView
}

func addBox() {
    let sideMaterial = SCNMaterial()

    sideMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orange
    sideMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true;

    let box = SCNBox(width: 0.3, height: 0.6, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0.005)
    box.materials = [sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial]

    let boxNode = SCNNode()
    boxNode.geometry = box
    boxNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -0.2)
    let scene = SCNScene()        
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
    parentNode = scene.rootNode
    parentNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1.0)       
    sceneView.scene = scene      
    // Set up SceneView2 (Right Eye)
    SceneView2.scene = scene
    SceneView2.showsStatistics = sceneView.showsStatistics
    SceneView2.isPlaying = true // Turn on isPlaying to ensure this ARSCNView recieves updates.
}

func movebox() {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let rotate = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 5, z: 0, duration: 20)
        let moveSequence = SCNAction.sequence([rotate])
        let moveLoop = SCNAction.repeatForever(moveSequence)
        self.parentNode.runAction(moveLoop)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? What is parentNode, and what is runAction?

Comment: Way more code than necessary. See [mcve]?

Comment: SceneKit isn’t really made to do multiple views on the same scene, especially when things like actions and physics get involved. What you need is for one view to render the same scene twice, which you can do with SCNTechnique. Pretty sure there’s a duplicate question about that, but it might take me a bit to dig up...

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) Every second line in your code block is empty: can you remove those (or the whole bunch and try re-inserting it)? Should make it easier to decide whether the tailing ´}´ is spurious or not, too.